# Select an observation if it has another within 24 hours of it

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a table that only populates entries of a contact to a customer at a business number if they were NOT first contacted at a home number within 24 hours prior to the attempt at the business number.

So if I have

```
DATA HAVE;
 INPUT ID RECORD DATETIME. TYPE;
 FORMAT RECORD DATETIME.;
 CARDS;
 1 17MAY2018:06:24:28 H
 1 18MAY2018:05:24:28 B
 1 20MAY2018:06:24:28 B
 2 20MAY2018:07:24:28 H
 2 20MAY2018:08:24:28 B
 2 22MAY2018:06:24:28 H
 2 24MAY2018:06:24:28 B
 3 25MAY2018:06:24:28 H
 3 25MAY2018:07:24:28 B
 3 25MAY2018:08:24:28 B
 4 26MAY2018:06:24:28 H
 4 26MAY2018:07:24:28 B
 4 27MAY2018:08:24:28 H
 4 27MAY2018:09:24:28 B
 5 28MAY2018:06:24:28 H
 5 29MAY2018:07:24:28 B
 5 29MAY2018:08:24:28 B
 ;
RUN;
```

I want to be able to get

```
1 20MAY2018:06:24:28 B
2 24MAY2018:06:24:28 B
5 29MAY2018:07:24:28 B
5 29MAY2018:08:24:28 B
```

I have tried adding a count to the ID but I'm not sure how I'd go about using that, or if there's a way to use a subquery within a proc sql to create a count of observations that have more than one in a 24 hour period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, [your approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55765230/1623007) will work, but will be *quite* messy with large numbers - as you're doing a cartesian join within ID.  If each ID has few records it's not so bad, but if each ID has many records you make a lot of connections.

Fortunately, there's an easy way to do this in SAS!

```
data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);  *for each ID:;
    set have;
    by id;    
    if first.id then last_home=0;   *initialize last_home to 0;
    if type='H' then last_home = record;  *if it is a home then save it aside;
    if type='B' and intck('Hour',last_home,record,'c') gt 24 then output;   *if it is business then check if 24 hours have passed;
  end;
  format last_home datetime.;
run;
```

A few notes:

- I use a DoW loop, but that really isn't mandatory, I just like it from a clarity perspective (it makes it clear I'm doing something at an ID-repetition level).  You could remove that loop and add a RETAIN for last_home and it would be the same.
- I use INTCK instead of INTNX - again this is for clarity, your INTNX is fine too, but INTCK just does the comparison, while INTNX is for advancing dates by an amount.  I use the one that matches what I am trying to do, so someone reading the code can see easily what I'm doing.

This will be much faster than SQL on larger datasets, if for no other reason than it only passes the data once.  SQL will necessarily do it multiple times, even if you don't separate HAVEA/HAVEB and do that within the SQL query.

Comment: It's so annoying, now that I see it it makes perfect sense but I couldn't for the life of me come up with it on my own.  With this data step, the primary needs before it are to ensure that the data is in a single table and sorted by ID then by record right?

Comment: Right.  And you could enforce the RECORD by adding that to the BY statement with no real issue.  It doesn't actually have to be in one dataset, you could do something similar if it's in two (either HAVEA and HAVEB, with a MERGE, or multiple datasets spanning multiple days, just by adding them to the SET statement).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out!

I have HAVEA and HAVEB tables hosting type H and type B entries respectively.

Then I ran the following PROC SQL's.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WANTA AS
SELECT A.RECORD AS PREVIOUS_CALL, B.* FROM HAVEB B
JOIN HAVEA A ON (B.ID=A.ID AND A.RECORD LE B.RECORD);

CREATE TABLE WANTB AS
SELECT * FROM WANTA
GROUP BY ID, RECORD
HAVING PREVIOUS_CALL = MAX(PREVIOUS_CALL);

CREATE TABLE WANTC AS
SELECT * FROM WANTB
WHERE INTNX('HOUR',RECORD,-24,'SAME') GT PREVIOUS_CALL;
QUIT;
```

Please let me know if this is not a sustainable answer for larger sums of data or if there is a much better method of approaching this.

Answer (score 0):

You perform a selection to get the final result set with out creating intermediate tables. Here are two alternatives:

**First way**

Similar to your 'figuring it out'.  A reflexive join with grouping detects the "to_home" calls prior to the "to_business" calls that did NOT occur in the last 24 hours (86,400 seconds)

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
  select distinct
    business.*
  from have as business
  join have as home
    on business.id = home.id
       & business.type = 'B'
       & home.type = 'H'
       & home.CALL_DT < business.CALL_DT
   group by
     business.call_dt
   having
     max(home.call_dt) < business.call_dt - 86400
       ;
```

**Second way**

Perform a NOT existential check, for a to_home call in prior 24hr, for every to_business call.

```
  create table want2 as
  select 
    business.*
  from
    have as business
  where
    business.type = 'B'
    and
    not exists (
      select * from have as home
      where home.id = business.id
        and home.type = 'H'
        and home.call_dt < business.call_dt
        and home.call_dt >= business.call_dt - 86400
    )
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A HASH solution does have some dependencies (amount of data and RAM)...but it is another alternative

```
DATA HAVE;
 INPUT ID RECORD DATETIME. TYPE $;
 FORMAT RECORD DATETIME.;
 CARDS;
 1 17MAY2018:06:24:28 H
 1 18MAY2018:05:24:28 B
 1 20MAY2018:06:24:28 B
 2 20MAY2018:07:24:28 H
 2 20MAY2018:08:24:28 B
 2 22MAY2018:06:24:28 H
 2 24MAY2018:06:24:28 B
 3 25MAY2018:06:24:28 H
 3 25MAY2018:07:24:28 B
 3 25MAY2018:08:24:28 B
 4 26MAY2018:06:24:28 H
 4 26MAY2018:07:24:28 B
 4 27MAY2018:08:24:28 H
 4 27MAY2018:09:24:28 B
 5 28MAY2018:06:24:28 H
 5 29MAY2018:07:24:28 B
 5 29MAY2018:08:24:28 B
 ;
RUN;

 /* Keep only HOME TYPE records and 
     rename RECORD for using in comparision */
Data HOME(Keep=ID RECORD rename=(record=hrecord));
 Set HAVE(where=(Type="H"));
Run;

Data WANT(Keep=ID RECORD TYPE);
   /* Use only BUSINESS TYPE records */
 Set HAVE(where=(Type="B"));

  /* Set up HASH object */    
 If _N_=1 Then Do;
   /* Multidata:YES for looping through 
       all successful FINDs */
  Declare HASH HOME(dataset:"HOME", multidata:'yes');
  home.DEFINEKEY('id');
  home.DEFINEDATA('hrecord');
  home.DEFINEDONE();
   /* To prevent warnings in the log */
  Call Missing(HRECORD);
 End;

   /* FIND first KEY match */
 rc=home.FIND();
   /* Successful FINDs result in RC=0 */
 Do While (RC=0);
   /* This will keep the result of the most recent, in datetime,
       HOME/BUS record comparision */
   If intck('Hour',hrecord,record,'c') > 24 Then Good_For_Output=1;
   Else Good_For_Output=0;
    /* Keep comparing HOME/BUS for all HOME records */
   rc=home.FIND_NEXT();
 End;

 If Good_For_Output=1 Then Output;
Run;
```